# Error installing packages in R Studio

Tags: r, install.packages

I updated the R and R Studio to the latest versions i.e R 3.2.0 and R studio  0.98.1103 on my 64-bit Windows 7 operating system.
When I try to install packages in R after this update the error is thrown:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  downloaded length 4878 != reported length 200
Error in install.packages : subscript out of bounds
```

Please help!

Comment: What happens when you try to install packages from Rgui?

Comment: Which packages? Any packages? Which CRAN mirror?

Comment: What was your exact command when you tried to install the packages?

Comment: @Roland - This error occurs:  
"Error in res0[, "Package"] : subscript out of bounds" followed by "Warning in install.packages :
  downloaded length 4878 != reported length 200
Error in install.packages : subscript out of bounds"

Comment: @Spacedman - Lately, the error occurs for every package I install. I was trying to install the "tm" package

Comment: @rmuc8 - I used install.packages() command

Comment: And what CRAN mirror are you using? Try another one.

Comment: @Spacedman -  I used http://cran.rstudio.com/ and http://ftp.iitm.ac.in/cran/ initially but these generated the same error. Then, I used the following command: 
`install.packages("tm", repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')` and that's when the package was successfully installed. Having said that, the above mentioned repos isn't available in the mirror list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
options(repos=structure(c(CRAN="http://cran.us.r-project.org")))
```

Now try installing any package. Hope it works